# Java extract duration by regex

Tags: java, regex

I've defined a pattern

```
(?:.*+)(?<amount>\\d++\\.?+\\d*+)(\\s*+)(?<unit>.++)
```

to match strings like

```
5-6 minutes
2 minutes
2.5 hours
1 to 2 minutes
~2 hours
```

I want to extract the last part of all the above, as

```
6 minutes
2 minutes
2.5 hours
2 minutes
2 hours
```

But the regex doesn't work :(
Thoughts?

Edit: `Pattern.compile("5-6 minutes").matcher().find()` should yield `true`, but is `false.`

Comment: Please show the code that does not work.

Comment: your example is not enough clear, can you make another input and output?

Comment: See edit.......

Comment: if i can understand you match should be minute or hour in the end and before that you should to have an integer or a double right?

Comment: @YCF_L Any string in the end preceded by a number (and maybe whitespace).

Comment: i think @WiktorStribiżew is amazing in regex haha ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look for partial matches at the end of the string. To do that, remove the `.*+` that prevents yout pattern from matching at all (the possessive quantifier turns off backracking), and restrict the `.+` with a pattern that matches only letters (`[a-zA-Z]+`), or non-whitespace chars (`\S+`), and add `$` end of string anchor. Use

```
(?<amount>\d*\.?\d+)\s*(?<unit>[a-zA-Z]+)$
```

with `Matcher#find()`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fYXD48/1).

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/SKM1xr):

```
String s = "5-6 minutes";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<amount>\\d*\\.?\\d+)\\s*(?<unit>[a-zA-Z]+)$");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
if (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0)); 
}
```